# When registering both onchange and onclick on a select, the click event is triggered twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Goal:** Have a `select` whose `option` have nested structure when user clicks on the `select`, but when user selects an `option` the option should be displayed "normally" (ie with no leading spaces).

**Attempted solution using JS and Jquery:** My JS is far from sophisticated so I apologize in advance :)


I attempted to use `.on("change")` and .`on("click")` to change the selected `option` value (by calling `.trim()` since I achieve the "nested" structure with `&nbsp;`). I'm also storing the original value of the selected `option` because I want to revert the `select` menu to its original structure in case the user selects another `option`.

**The problem**: The function registered for `.on("click")` is called twice, thus the `select` value immediately resets itself to its original value.

I suspect there is a much, much easier solution using CSS. I will be happy to accept an answer that will suggest such solution.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dv6kky43/9/

```
<form>
  <select id="select">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="a">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;a</option>
    <option value="b">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;b</option>
  </select>
</form>
<textarea id="output"/>
```

```
var orig;
var output = $("#output");
output.val("");

function onDeviceSelection(event){
  output.val(output.val() + "\nonDeviceSelection");
  var select = event.target;
  orig = select.selectedOptions[0].text;
  select.selectedOptions[0].text = select.selectedOptions[0].text.trim()

}

function resetDeviceSelectionText(event) {
  output.val(output.val() + "\nresetDeviceSelectionText");
  var select = event.target;
  if (orig !== undefined){
    select.selectedOptions[0].text = orig;
  }
}

$("#select").on("change", onDeviceSelection);
$("#select").on("click", resetDeviceSelectionText);
```

Comment: When you `change` the selected element you also `click` on it. Events bubble up.

Comment: @JonasW. I tried to call `event.stopPropogation` in the function I registered for the `change` event but that didn't work either.

Comment: you `change` the select but you `click` on the option. The option click event bubbles up to the select, so both click & change get called shortly after another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using jQuery, why not  utilize `data` function to store the original value. This way you will also be able to specify different nest levels.

```js
(function($){
  $(document).on('change', 'select', function(event) {
    $(this).find('option').each(function(index, element){
      var $option = $(element);

      // Storing original value in html5 friendly custom attribute.
      if(!$option.data('originalValue')) {
        $option.data('originalValue', $option.text());
      }
      
      if($option.is(':selected')) {
        $option.html($option.data('originalValue').trim());
      } else {
        $option.html($option.data('originalValue'));
      }
    })
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <select id="select">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="a">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;a</option>
    <option value="b">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;b</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Once caveat I see is, the selected option will appear trimmed on the list as well, if dropdown is opened after a previous selection has been made:

[image]

Will it still work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of keeping the state of the selected element i would simply go over all options and add the space if that option is not selected:

```
function onDeviceSelection(event){
  // Update textarea
  output.val(output.val() + "\nonDeviceSelection");
  // Higlight the selected
  const {options, selectedIndex} = event.target;
  for(let i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
      options[i].innerHTML = (i === selectedIndex ? "":"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;") + options[i].text.trim();

}

$("#select").on("change", onDeviceSelection);
```

Note that you need to use `innerHTML` to set the whitespace...

Comment: Thanks, but this does not restore the select menu to its original state when selecting another option.

Comment: @deepspace needed to fix some things, now it [works](http://jsbin.com/yabadolefo/edit?output)